# Jackson XML List Elements Match Their Root Name

Tags: java, xml, jackson, jackson-dataformat-xml

Using Jackson's `XmlMapper`, is there a way to have the names of elements of a list of objects match the `localName` given in `@JacksonXmlRootElement`?

For example, given the following classes

```
interface Foo {}

@JacksonXmlRootElement(localName = "bar")
class Bar implements Foo {}

@JacksonXmlRootElement(localName = "baz")
class Baz implements Foo {}

@JacksonXmlRootElement(localName = "container")
class FooContainer {
    @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(useWrapping = false)
    private List<Foo> foos;

    FooContainer(List<Foo> foos) {
        this.foos = foos;
    }

    public List<Foo> getFoos() {
        return foos;
    }
}
```

Using the `XmlMapper`

```
FooContainer container = new FooContainer(Arrays.asList(new Bar(), new Baz()));
XmlMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper();
xmlMapper.writeValueAsString(container);
```

We get the following XML

```
<container>
  <foos/>
  <foos/>
</container>
```

Is there a way to instead get this?

```
<container>
  <bar/>
  <baz/>
</container>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't been able to find a way to do this in Jackson, but it's almost trivial in JAXB.

```
interface Foo {}

class Bar implements Foo {}

class Baz implements Foo {}

@XmlRootElement(name = "container")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
class FooContainer {
    @XmlElements({
        @XmlElement(name = "bar", type = Bar.class),
        @XmlElement(name = "baz", type = Baz.class)
    })
    private List<Foo> foos;

    FooContainer() {}

    FooContainer(List<Foo> foos) {
        this.foos = foos;
    }

    public List<Foo> getFoos() {
        return foos;
    }
}
```

Unmarshalling:

```
FooContainer container = new FooContainer(Arrays.asList(new Bar(), new Baz()));

JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(FooContainer.class);
Marshaller marshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
marshaller.marshal(container, System.out);
```